# What's the purpose of the Ubuntu Online Accounts extension in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, online-accounts, firefox-extensions

On my Ubuntu 14.04, there is a Firefox extension "Ubuntu Online Accounts 0.5", installed by the package `xul-ext-webaccounts` (which is in the default install).

What is the purpose of this extension? What will stop working if I disable it?

There seems to be no documentation in the package, the description page of the extension is basically empty, and the only link points to https://launchpad.net/webaccounts-browser-extension, on which I also cannot find information on its purpose.

Of course I suspect it is related to the Online Accounts dialog in the System Control Center, however Firefox is not listed as an application in that dialog, and when I visit a page such as Twitter with Firefox for which I have an account set up under Online Accounts, nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, the https://launchpad.net/online-accounts-documentation website is very sparse.

Comment: have you read: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnlineAccounts
What the online accounts basically does is giving you the ability to be on facebook/twitter/whatever ALL THE TIME (and upload photo's etc from your desktop directly)!!!!
The extension recognizes websites that are compatible and gives you the dialog to integrate facebook/twitter/whatever with your ubuntu. All it does is create the popup for a (not previously visited/integrated) website that is compatible with online accounts to integrate it into the online accounts stuff.

Comment: not 100% sure but like 80%, so I added it as a comment and not an answer. Can someone confirm that this is ALL the browser extension does??

Comment: @Arno I do know the popup asking for website integration, but this just adds websites to the launcher, doesn't it? I assumed the popup comes from one of the two other plugins that Ubuntu installs. Is it really related to the Online Accounts feature? It does not ask me when I log into Twitter, for example. Plus your link does not mention about the browser plugin.

Comment: true and true, but as you said you already have an account for twitter in your online accounts program so it should just ignore it. It will add a launcher for for example gmail but if I'm not mistaken it will not generate such a launcher for for example facebook. it will just add it to the active online accounts (like your twitter).
There is a simple method for finding out. Try it with a website that is compatible with online accounts and see what happens.

Comment: I deleted my Online Account for Twitter, restarted Firefox and visited twitter.com. After confirming the integration popup, Twitter was added to my launcher, but nothing happened to the Online Accounts. Even when I click on that Twitter icon in the launcher a browser window opens with the normal login page for Twitter and no integration with Online Accounts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so I decided to investigate in the source code. The extension itself consists only of a few lines of Javascript in the file [`/usr/lib/xul-ext/webaccounts/content/browser.js`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~online-accounts/webaccounts-browser-extension/13.10/view/head:/firefox-extension/content/browser.js.in) that only loads the library `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/webaccounts-browser-extension/libwebaccounts.so` and calls it with info about the currently visited page.

The package `webaccounts-extension-common` that contains this library also has a file [`/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.webcredentials.capture.gschema.xml`](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~online-accounts/webaccounts-browser-extension/13.10/view/head:/lib/data/com.canonical.webcredentials.capture.gschema.xml) that contains the gsettings configuration options of this package. There is only a single one, which lists the sites for which the extension was already active once and won't ask again. In my case, it contained `twitter.com`, which is why I did not notice anything when visiting Twitter. This blacklist can be cleared with the following command:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.webcredentials.capture dontask-accounts
```

The next time I visited Twitter, the Ubuntu Control Center opened with the Online Accounts dialog, so that is the desired effect of this plugin.

However, the [source code of the library](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~online-accounts/webaccounts-browser-extension/13.10/view/head:/lib/webaccounts/login-handler.c) shows that there should be more. It contains a function `webaccounts_store_login` that has the purpose of automatically adding the Twitter/etc. account you just used in the browser to the Ubuntu Online Accounts, such that the desktop integration just works immediately after you used the site once in the browser. This is of course a nice integration. However, this does not work for me (no account is added, only the accounts window opens), and there is a two-year old [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/webaccounts-browser-extension/+bug/1029396) that indicates that this is the same for others as well.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! It's extremely annoying to find something like this installed with no explanation, even more so if it exchanges login information with the environment!

Answer (score 0):

Packages like that installed by Firefox are designed to provide extra functionality, some of which isn't noticeable. Most of them  make some of the settings and other data available offline, AFAIK. Removing this package shouldn't remove any functionality from Firefox or the pages it applies to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but you also don't know what it actually does? It needs to have a purpose, otherwise it wouldn't be there, right?